# How to identify a presentation in PowerPoint?

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint, office-interop, office-addins

Normally, to identify a shape in a slide, we use PowerPoint.Shape.Id

to identify a slide in a presentation, we use PowerPoint.Slide.SlideId

but I don't know how to identify a presentation in a PowerPoint application. Assume that we have a collection of presentation being opened, how can we identify a presentation in that collection?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use the `Application.ActiveWindow` Property. I think this is probably what you are looking for? I think the question needs to be more specific in what identifies which presentation you would like to return but this will put you on the right track.

More info here:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff745295(v=office.15).aspx

Answer (score 3):

The Application object has a Presentations collection.
The Presentation objects in that collection have a .FullName property which includes the full path to the presentation, assuming it's been saved.

That would uniquely identify the presentation on a given system.